# $C(X,K)$ isomorphic to polynomial algebra $K[t]$

Tags: general-topology

For $X$ a topological space and $K$ a topological field of characteristic $0$, let $C(X,K)$ be the set of all continuous functions $f:X\to K$. The set $C(X,K)$ turns to a ring with point-wise addition and multiplication:
\begin{align}
(f+g)(x)&=f(x)+g(x)\\
(fg)(x) & =f(x)g(x).
\end{align}
I'm looking for a topological space $X$ such that $C(X,K)\cong K[t]$.
Or I'm looking for a proof that shows such space does not exist.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the isomorphism as abstract rings, or as $K$-algebras ?

Comment: @Max Well, really answer to any of them will be appreciated!

Comment: I do,'t have a full answer yet, but if we're thinking in terms of $K$-algebras, you can try to prove the following things : the function $f:X\to K$ that generates $C(X,K)$ (as a $K$-algebra) is surjective, and the field $K$ must be algebraically closed.

Comment: Ok, I know how to prove that no such $X$ exists for $K=\mathbb{C}$ with the usual topology, but my argument uses $\exp$ so it will only work for algebraically closed topological fields where there is a nice relation between $K$ and $K^\times$.

Comment: @Max Why no post this as an answer, then? An answer for a special case is still a useful one!

Comment: @lisyarus you are right, I posted what I know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a full answer, but just leads. First of all, as discussed in the comments, I'll consider that we're asking for a $K$-algebra isomorphism, not just an isomorphism as abstract rings.

Note that if $X$ is such a space, the $K$-algebra structure map is $\lambda \mapsto $ the constant map with value $\lambda$.

Now, if $f:X\to K$ is continuous and nonconstant, then under the isomorphism $C(X,K)\to K[t]$ it is sent to a nonconstant polynomial, hence to a noninvertible element of the algebra.

But now we see that if $f:X\to K$ doesn't vanish, i.e. factors through $K^\times$, then it's invertible in $C(X,K)$, thus in $K[t]$, thus it must be a constant map:

> there are only constant maps $X\to K^\times$.

Now let $f$ be the antecedent of $t$. In particular, for all non constant $P\in K[t]$, $P(f)$ is sent to $P(t)$, thus is noninvertible; and therefore it has a zero, say $x$. Then $f(x)$ is a root of $P$: every nonconstant polynomial has a root, which means that $K$ is algebraically closed.

> If such an $X$ exists, $K$ is algebraically closed.

Notice that with the same reasoning, we get that for all $\lambda$, $f-\lambda$ is non invertible, thus $f$ is surjective.

> There is a surjective continuous map $X\to K$ which generates $C(X,K)$.

Now if we have a nonconstant continuous map $K\to K^\times$, putting the first and last yellow results together, we get a contradiction. This is the case for instance with $K=\mathbb{C}$ with the usual topology, where $\exp$ is continuous and nonconstant.

> There is no such space for $\mathbb{C}$. More generally, for every topological algebraically closed field with a continuous nonconstant map $K\to K^\times$, there is no such $X$.

I don't know whether all topological algebraically closed fields have such a map. What about $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ for instance ?

In any case, it feels like the constraint "there is no nonconstant continuous $g:X\to K^\times$" is a pretty big one; but I don't know how to make that precise yet. The isomorphism with $K[t]$ seems to suggest that $X$ doesn't have many opens, but this constraint suggests that it has a lot...

Comment: thanks a billion!

Comment: A continuous nonconstant map $K\to K^\times$ will exist if $K$ is disconnected (take a locally constant map that is not constant).  So that rules out $\overline{Q}$ with its usual topology.

Comment: @EricWofsey : indeed that rules out tons of examples actually (many algebraically closed subfields of $\mathbb{C}$ with their usual topology I would guess, and -though I'm not sure- the $p$-adic fields)